# Getting an error when I am connecting CRM with Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to integrate my Salesforce CRM Account with my Salesforce Marketing Account.

I am following steps that are given in the Trailhead: Marketing Cloud Connect.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/finish-mc-connect-configuration

While performing the steps under section "Connect to Marketing Cloud Within Salesforce CRM", I am getting the below error when I trying to connect my Marketing Cloud Account via Salesforce CRM

Error: authorizationCode cannot be null.

Comment: I think it's best to open a support case.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure to follow all of the steps in the following documentation, "Connect the Clouds", as it encompasses everything needed to properly set up the integration between SFDC and SFMC

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_connect_the_clouds.htm&type=5

The Trail, while valuable, may miss a few necessary items.